# Need to apply an if condition based on a check in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am new to Powershell. I am actually getting the details of the azure data factory linked services but after get I need to use contains to check if the element exists. In python I would just check if string in a list but powershell not quite sure. Please check the code below.

```
$output = Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -DataFactoryName "xxxxxxxx" | Format-List
```

The output of the below is :
sample output given below

```
LinkedServiceName : abcdef
ResourceGroupName : ghijk
DataFactoryName   : lmnopq
Properties        : Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.AzureDatabricksLinkedService
```

So now I try to do this:

```
if ($output.Properties  -contains "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.AzureDatabricksLinkedService") { 
  Write-Output "test output"
}
```

But $output.Properties gives us the properties of that json.

I need to check if "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.AzureDatabricksLinkedService" exists in output variable and perform the required operations. Please help me on this.

Comment: I am not going to answer but ```$output = Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -DataFactoryName "xxxxxxxx" | Format-List``` needs to be converted to an object with something like ```$output = Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -DataFactoryName "xxxxxxxx" | convertfrom-csv``` or ```ConvertFrom-Json```
And then I would use ```-matches``` in the last if.

Comment: If you want to do anything further with the returned object(s), the remove `| Format-List`. `Format-*` cmdlets are for **display purposes only**

Comment: I was able to figure this out but when I give $output.Properties and -contains it displays the properties of that json rather than listing "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.AzureDatabricksLinkedService" . Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The `-contains` operator requires a collection and an element. Here's a basic example of its proper use:

```
$collection = @(1,2,3,4)
$element1 = 5
$element2 = 3
if ($collection -contains $element1) {'yes'} else {'no'}
if ($collection -contains $element2) {'yes'} else {'no'}
```

What you've done is ask PowerShell to look in an object that isn't a collection for an element of type `[string]` and value equal to the name of that same object.

What you need to do is inspect this object:

```
$output.Properties | format-list *
```

Then once you figure out what needs to be present inside of it, create a new condition.

```
$output.Properties.something -eq 'some string value'
```

...assuming that your value is a string, for example.

---

I would recommend watching some beginner [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6D474E721138865A).

Comment: I was able to figure this out but when I give $output.Properties and -contains it displays the properties of that json rather than listing "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.AzureDatabricksLinkedService" . Why is that happening ?

Comment: Because it's an object. It seems to me that you want to look inside that object and test one or more of its properties to pass some condition. I'm not sure why you would want the string name of the object, but I think you can get that if you use `$output.Properties.ToString()`.